# How to perform a web request with ntml authentication

Tags: rust

I tried to perform a web post request in rust with the ntlm authentification but I can't figure out.

Here is my actual code:

```rust
let mut map = HashMap::new();
map.insert("test", "test");
let client = reqwest::Client::new();
let res = client.post(format!("{}/create", URL))
        .json(&map)
        .send()
        .await?;
```

So to add the ntlm authentication, I tried the curl crate with the "ntlm" feature enabled:

```rust
let mut easy = Easy::new();
easy.url(format!("{}/create", URL)).unwrap();
easy.post(true).unwrap();
easy.post_field_size(map.len() as u64).unwrap();

let mut transfer = easy.transfer();
transfer.read_function(|buf| {
    Ok(map.read(buf).unwrap_or(0))
}).unwrap();
transfer.perform().unwrap();
```

Sadly, I got this error:

```
Ok(map.read(buf).unwrap_or(0))
   |                ^^^^ method not found in `HashMap<&str, String>`
```

I understand that I need to convert my HashMap as bytes, but I can't find an easy way to do that, I tried "as_bytes()" but it doesn't work also.

My last question, this crate is a good way to do my ntlm authentication automatically?

Comment: You're asking about several things here. You should ask about one topic per question. How to serialize a HashMap in this context is unrelated to NTLM authentication.

Comment: My question is more related to the NTLM authentication, I will find a way for the hashmap no worries :)

Comment: It's not clear to me what your question about NTLM authentication is. If your question is simply "does this crate support NTLM authentication" then the answer seems to be "yes." If you are having a specific problem getting it to work, then I'm not seeing that information.

Comment: Okay, you answered correctly to my question, I just find a decent crate to make post requests with the NTLM authentication, if you know a better crate or more used crate to do that, I'm interested also, now I will find a way to pass a hashmap as post parameter with this library.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.